# Expected value of log sigmoid function to a normal distribution

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, logistic-regression

Is there an analytical solution for the expected value of log sigmoid function to a normal distribution. This corresponds to the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
     \log\left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(-x)}\right)
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}
     \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
     dx
$$

I checked with Wolfram|Alpha, but didn't get any answer.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is below.

Your integral is
$$
\begin{split}
I &= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}
     \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
        \log\left(1+\exp(-x)\right)
        \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
        dx \\
  &= \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
     \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}
        \log\left(1+e^{-\mu - \sigma u}\right)
        e^{-u^2/2}
        du
\end{split}
$$
and now expand $\ln(1+y)$ into Taylor series, and integrate term-by-term. Not sure If you can find a closed form expression for the final result, but you may have a good chance.

A possibly good approximation is to cut off the Taylor series after a couple of terms and integrate by parts what you can in the result.

Comment: Thanks. @gt6989b I think there is no analytical solution for this integral, so approximation is necessary. I tried Gaussian quadrature, the result is good.